# iOS swift firebase firestore crashed at [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@“org.cocoapods.grpcpp”]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I use  firebase firestore to develop  . In this morning , no crash

as night, it gives exception at [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@“org.cocoapods.grpcpp”] as screenshot stated . I have no clue on my pod settings or code... Would you please tell me what to fix?

Below is my screen shot :

[image]

Below is my code  :

```
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (result , error) in
        guard let authResult = result else {
            return
        }
        let user = authResult.user
        let isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous  // true
        if(isAnonymous){
            let uid = user.uid
            User.shared.userId = uid
            print("user id : \(User.shared.userId)")
           self.writeProgressInitial()

        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




   func writeProgressInitial() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userRef = db.collection("user").document(User.shared.userId)
        userRef.getDocument { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if (querySnapshot?.get("progress") == nil) {
                   var  dataDict : Dictionary<String , Any> = [:]
                   dataDict["progress"]  = 0
                   userRef.setData(dataDict)
                }else{
                    let dict = querySnapshot?.data()
                    let sssresult = dict!.filter{ $0.key == "progress" }.first?.value as? Int ?? 0
                    User.shared.progress = sssresult
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Personally, I have tested that even using Dispatch async to update the progress but it fails .

Below is my Installed dependencies  :

```
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
Installing Cosmos (19.0.3)
Installing Firebase (6.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.2)
Installing FirebaseAuth (6.2.3)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.0.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (1.5.1)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.5)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (2.0.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.1.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.3.0)
Installing JGProgressHUD (2.0.4)
Installing Protobuf (3.9.2)
Installing QuickTableViewController (1.2.0)
Installing SDWebImage (5.2.0)
Installing SimpleRoundedButton (1.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (0.0.9)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.21.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22)
Installing nanopb (0.3.901)
```

Comment: I have same problem...

Comment: Finally solved the problem. In my case `$PRODUCT_NAME` contains multi byte character.

Comment: That is strange that changing this shall make my Firestore not working . If I  change app name on Info plist, the Firestore is working

Comment: $PRODUCT_NAME cannot allow Chinese characters.